# How should I use key-value coding with the ID type?

Tags: cocoa, key-value

How can I use key-value coding messages (setValue:ForKey: and so on) with `id` type? Key-value coding protocol is implemented as an informal protocol, so it is not included in `<NSObject>` protocol and I can't simply say `id<NSObject> setValue:ForKey:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method. The compiler won't emit warnings for unknown methods on `id` variables.

```
id myObj = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
[myObj setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. I was using `id<MyProtocol> setValue:ForKey:` and `MyProtocol` inherits `NSObject`. In this case  compiler emits warnings. Is it possible to find workaround here? I thought it would be better to say 'hey this id means MyProtocol kind of objects' in code.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, the compiler's behavior toward `id<MyProtocol>` is a little strange IMO. In that case, the only (dirty) workaround I see to get rid of the compiler warning is to actually redeclare the `setValue:forKey:` method (and others you want to use) in your protocol.

Comment: Or redeclare the variable without the protocol specifier.